# Text from attribute table as symbols (font marker?) not showing correct in legend (QGIS)

Tags: legend, markers, font, data-defined-override

I need to place symbols (point layer) with abbreviations from a attribute table. I solved that with "font marker" and data defined override as you can see in the screenshot below. The result in the map is exactly what I need, but the legend isn't. In the legend, every type of symbol got a "A" instead the abbreviation from the classification.

How can I solve that? Or is there a other way to get the same result but with a useful legend?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve this by setting the layer's style not to `Single Symbol`, but to `Categorized`, based on the `Value` that comes from the field in your attribute table containing the abbreviations. Then click on the symbol and set data driven override there, see:

[image]

Now open a new layout, add a map and legend. In the legend's `Item properties`, expand Legend items and uncheck the box `Auto update`. You now have an identical, default `A` font marker symbol for each entry, but color and legend text are already adapted to each item:

[image]

To adapt the symbol, you must manually change it: double click on the first one, check the box `Custom Symbol`, and click below on the symbol:
[image]

In the opening dialog, select `Font Marker` and manually insert the character you want to display. Data driven override based on the attribute value does not work here (the attributes are not available):

[image]

Comment: That's a way, but I don't want to set it up manually since I have to do that with about 200 abbreviations. They also could change so I need a "dynamic" solution.

Comment: Yes, the solution is not ideal, indeed, especially for larger data sets.

Comment: Maybe in the layer styling panel using the `Advanced` option / `Match to saved symbols` or `Match to symbols from file…` could help?